# How do I change the layout of a Grid bound inside another?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a `Grid` inside a `ListBox` bound to a list of items. When I press a global 'edit' button, I want a series of checkboxes to appear in the `Grid`. I was planning on doing this in a similar fashion to how orientation change is handled, however I can't figure out how to access the bound grid to change the column properties

Here's my XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <CheckBox 
                    Grid.Column="0" 
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="1" 
                    IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
                </CheckBox>
                <TextBlock 
                    Grid.Column="0" 
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                    Text="{Binding ItemName}">
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I was going to set the `CheckBox` and `TextBlock` ColumnSpan to 2 on edit mode, then back to 1/3 on cancel. But I can't access those.

Is there a smarter way to do this?

I also considered setting visibility on the Checkbox to a bound value, but this will mean the grid will still have a gap when not in edit mode.

Comment: Is the `Grid` actually necessary, or would something simpler like a `StackPanel` with Horizontal `Orientation` suffice?

Comment: `I also considered setting visibility on the Checkbox to a bound value, but this will mean the grid will still have a gap when not in edit mode.` Not if you set the column width to "Auto"

Comment: KooKiz, thats a good point